# jquery toggle search bar not closing on click, what can it be?

Tags: jquery

I'm just wondering why my search bar isn't closing, here is my code:

```js
$(".search-icon").click(function(event) {
  $(".search-box").toggle();
  $("input[type='text']").focus();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  background: #E8E8E4;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="search-icon" src="wp-content/themes/business-events-toronto/assets/search-icon.svg" />
<div class="search-box">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://localhost:8888/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it appears to work fine. Please check the console for errors, and ensure you've loaded jQuery and are running your JS at a point when the DOM has loaded, eg. at the end of the body or in a document.ready handler.

Comment: Oyyy thank you! I'm working on wordpress so still getting used to it. Thanks :)